# Mouse Scroll Wheel impossibly fast

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

I just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 23.04 (I am using KDE) and now my mouse scroll wheel way too fast. My mouse is a Logitech G502 Lightspeed (Wireless), which has been working splendidly for a few years, until now. This mouse has two scroll speed options. One is the normal clicking-slow speed, which normally scrolls about 3 lines per click. The other is smooth-fast speed, which does more.

Now the speed is so unusable that I basically can't use my mouse wheel anymore. these slow click mode will scroll through more than half a page (about 66% of visible area).

I have tried the imwheel (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IMWheel) approach but the problem is that is for increasing speed. Each of these modifiers after the button in the configuration files are repetition multipliers. ***I want to slow down my mouse speed.***

System Info:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.3.0-060300-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 62.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090/PCIe/SSE2
Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: X570 AORUS ELITE WIFI
```

I don't know if the recent Ubuntu changes to the Wayland system have anything to do with this problem? Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this application dependent (some applications act differently) or the  problem is the same in any application you tried?

Comment: @FedKad It was in all applications, Dolphin, Chromium, Brave, Konsole, Pidgin...

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the solution: Unplug the USB dongle and then plug it back in (same usb port, no need to change). I did this while the system was suspended in sleep. This fixed the problem. Hope this helps someone else.

UPDATE: Also if your mouse has a power-switch, you can try toggling the mouse off-then-on again and it may work just as well.

Comment: This may be a temporary solution. Please test after reboot.

Comment: thank you, this worked for me as well on Fedora with GNOME on X11 and a Logitech MX Master 3